# Разница между win 32 console application и clr console application

Tags: c++

Только начал изучать c++ и не могу понять, для чего существует одно, а для чего другое. И почему у них разные элементы языка (например, cout и write)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

win 32 console application и clr console - первое - нативный код, второе - код для .NET. Хотя названия и похожие, но это два достаточно разных языка.
Если хотите учить С++, то лучше выбирайте первое. Если хочется .NET, то лучше уже брать С#.

Вторая половинка вопроса. Между cout и write разница в том, что cout (а если правильнее, то std::cout) - это стандартный вывод в консоль для с++. write же получает дескприптор, куда выводить. Может к примеру в файл или сокет. И является функцией операционной системы. Если углубиться в детали, то cout работает в конечном счете через write (либо у них есть общая функция, которую они используют).

Comment: спасибо. выбрать сам еще, думаю, не смогу. просто читаю книгу и тут рассматриваются как win32 так и clr консольные приложения

Comment: Изучите win32 часть - потом, с большой вероятностью легко сможете писать на с++ под линукс, под разные железяки.

Изучите .NET часть - будете только под винду писать (да, есть Mono, но... это отдельная история).

Comment: Странный совет. win32api гораздо сложнее posix.

Comment: Ну раз Вам попроще нужно, тогда выбирайте свое.
Но никто не мешает программировать под винду (делая консольные программы и не использовать win32api напрямую).